# How to get subtree of json containing known object

Tags: bash, jq, i3

I want to extract the subtree containing the focused window from `i3-msg -t get_tree` with `jq`. I know the focused window can be found with

`i3-msg -t get_tree | jq ".. | (.nodes? // empty)[] | select(.focused == true)"`

A simple example would be:

```
{
  "node": [
    {
      "node": {
        "foo": "bar"
      }
    },
    {
      "node": {
        "foo": "foo"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

And the output should if searching for a `node` containg `.foo == "bar"` should return

```
{
  "node": [
    {
      "node": {
        "foo": "bar"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

But I can't seem to find a proper method to extract the subtree spanning from the root to this node.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
.node |= map(select(.node.foo == "bar"))
```

This concept is referred to as [Update assignment](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/v1.6/#Assignment)

Comment: After some digging I found that this solution yielded the best results when filtering out the elements that had non-empty nodes
`i3-msg -t get_tree | jq ".. | (.nodes? // empty)[] | .nodes |= map(select(.nodes[].focused == true)) | select(.nodes != [])"`

Comment: @vintnes - The term "complex assignment" refers to assignments in which the LHS is a complex term.  Here the LHS is a simple term.

Comment: @peak The documentation varies heavily across versions; you can call it whatever you want. I reverted your edit because you broke my link.

Comment: @vintnes - Sorry if I broke a link.  In v1.3, v1.4, v1.5 and v1.6 of the documentation, the section on "Assignment" includes the subsection on `|=`.  Similarly for the "development" version (https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#Assignment)

Answer (score 2):

The original question has two distinct sub-questions, one related to the use of `..` without reference to a posted JSON sample, and the other based on a specific type of JSON input.  This response uses a strategy based on using `paths` along the lines of:

```
reduce pv as [$p,$v] (null; setpath($p; $v))
```

This may or may not handle arrays as desired, depending in part on what is desired.  If `null` values in arrays are not wanted in general, then adding a call to `walk/1` as follows would be appropriate:

```
walk(if type == "array" then map(select(. != null)) else . end)
```

Alternatively, if the `null` values that are present in the original must be preserved, the strategy detailed in the *Appendix* below may be used.

(1) Problem characterized by using ..

```
def pv:
 paths as $p
 | getpath($p)
 | . as $v
 | (.nodes? // empty)[] | select(.focused == true)
 | [$p,$v];

reduce pv as [$p,$v] (null; setpath($p; $v))
```

As mentioned above, to eliminate all the nulls in all arrays, you could tack on a call to `walk/1`.  Otherwise, if the `null` values inserted in arrays by `setpath` to preserve aspects of the original structure, see the *Appendix* below.

(2) For the sample JSON, the following suffices:

```
def pv:
 paths as $p
 | getpath($p)
 | . as $v
 | (.node? // empty) | select(.foo == "bar")
 | [$p,$v];

reduce pv as [$p,$v] (null; setpath($p; $v))
```

For the given sample, this produces:

```
{"node":[{"node":{"foo":"bar"}}]}
```

For similar inputs, if one wants to eliminate `null` values from arrays, simply tack on the call to `walk/1` as before; see also the *Appendix* below.

### Appendix

If the `null` values potentially inserted into arrays by `setpath` to preserve the original structure are not wanted, the simplest would be to change `null` values in the original JSON to some distinctive value (e.g. ":null:"), perform the selection, trim the `null` values, and then convert the distinctive value back to `null`.

#### Example

For example, consider this variant of the foo/bar example:

```
{
  "node": [
    {
      "node": {
        "foo": "foo0"
      }
    },
    {
      "node": {
        "foo": "bar",
        "trouble": [
          null,
          1,
          null
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "node": {
        "foo": "foo1"
      }
    },
    {
      "node": {
        "foo": "bar",
        "trouble": [
          1,
          2,
          3
        ]
      }
    }
  ],
  "nodes": [
    {
      "node": {
        "foo": "foo0"
      }
    },
    {
      "node": {
        "foo": "bar",
        "trouble": [
          null,
          1,
          null
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Using ":null:" as the distinctive value, the following variant of the "main" program previously shown for this case may be used:

```
walk(if type == "array" then map(if . == null then ":null:" else . end) else . end)
| reduce pv as [$p,$v] (null; setpath($p; $v))
| walk(if type == "array"
       then map(select(. != null) | if . == ":null:" then null else . end)
       else . end)
```

Comment: `walk/1` is very powerful.  One question: suppose the selected subtree has `null` array elements that shouldn't be removed.  Do you know an easy way to limit it to the "upper" part of the result where all the `null` array elements are consequences of `setpath`?

Comment: Looking at [`walk/1`](https://github.com/stedolan/jq/blob/master/src/builtin.jq#L255) I suspect computing the max depth from `getpath` and passing it to a `walk/2` that stopped at a depth limit might work.

Comment: @jq170727 - Please see the update (especially the Appendix).  One semantically equivalent alternative would be to use a special version of setpath that employs a distinctive value instead of null, but it would be much more complex. Any other strategy will either fail or be very complex to implement.